# Do I need to use the password input field for desired passwords in a registration form?

Tags: php, html, forms, security

Im building a simple registration form in PHP. I am wondering if there will be a security issue if I decide to use a simple input field instead of a password input field for the user's desired password. I've seen other sites that don't use the password input during registration and after some googling I can't find a conclusive answer either way.

I would prefer to use a normal text field because it would be easier for the user during registration but I am concerned there will be some way for 3rd parties to capture these.

Comment: I think thats just a visual thing so noone can see looking over your shoulder, but it is sent in plain text to server unless you use encryption or SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between an `<input type="password" />` and an `<input type="text" />` is that the password one gets all the characters masked with whatever the browser decides (bullet points/asterisks/whatever).

The only point is to ensure that people looking over ones shoulders can't see the password as it is being typed in.

If the communication to the server is not secure, it makes zero difference whether the field is of type password or not (it makes no difference if the communication is encrypted either, BTW). That is, if the information is sensitive, you should use a secure channel (and the password field doesn't do anything in this respect).

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference is that they can't sign up with someone standing behind them, because the password will be visible on their screen.

The password is transmitted in plain text either way unless you use https.

Keep in mind that your user's may not know that this is the only difference and may lose confidence in your site, because they are so accustomed to passwords being hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Password fields were meant to prevent shouldering. I.e. when a user is typing his password and someone looks at the screen over his shoulder and can easily see the tired password.

If you believe that's not an issue, you can use normal inputs.

There is no difference whatsoever aside from that. Both field are sent in the same way, be it pain text or encrypted over to the server. The difference isisual only.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will show the text the user inputs as texts and does not mask it. Also some browsers might store the value the user put in and offers it the next time someone opens the page.

Also most browsers will not offer the "save this password" option since they do not recognize it as a password field.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer, because browsers may treat password fields the way they like. Some of the possible features have been described in other answers rather well. In addition, browsers may treat password fields differently from text input fields when the user e.g. tells the browser clear cached information.

In general, any security-related features in browsers should be expected to treat `input type=password` as password input and all other input elements as something else.

Hiding user input with asterisks is mostly a nuisance, admittedly. It was originally based on the idea that people use computers in classrooms, public premises, etc. This aspect is still partly relevant. But the long-term solution is probably that browsers let the user decide whether a password is echoed as unmasked. (Some browsers already leave the most recently typed character unmasked.)

If you decide to use a text input field for reading a password, then adding the attribute `autocomplete=off spellcheck=false` may help a bit.

It’s also possible to have both types of fields, letting the user decide which one to use. The problem is that this might be confusing and even look suspicious to users.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, I didn't even realize those attributes existed.